# I have problem to run flutter in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

when I wanna run main.dart in android studio I get this error
I did everything I saw in stack overflow and all of internet but it still doesn't work

[Android Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpGqS.png)

Comment: did you add your gradle path to android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that you are trying to access does not exists try using a valid path.
Try using / instead of \

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, it solved.
it was because of my pc user name,  it was " 0&1 " and android studio doesn't support " &" 
thank you again